# !ls in Jupyter notebook (Python 3)

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

If I use:

```
!ls '/Users/martyn/Documents/rawData'
```

it gives me a list of the files in the required directory.

But I want to paramterize this. I tried:

```
pathData = '/Users/martyn/Documents/rawData'
!ls pathData
```

But this gives the error:

```
ls: pathData: No such file or directory
```

I can see the problem ... but can't see how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

You probably need

```
!ls {pathData}
```

or

```
!ls $pathData
```

Answer (score 2):

You can list the files and folder in any directory using folling command

```
%ls pathData
```

for current directory use

```
%ls
```

if you want to go one folder back you can use

```
%ls '../'
```

For two folders back

```
%ls '../../'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only `%ls` gives you the list in your current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can also use:

```
from glob import glob

#path_list=glob("put your file path here.extension")
path_list=glob("C:/Users/..../PYTHON/module1/data.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
import subprocess
print(subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-lhS']).decode('utf-8'))
```